# Write personnalized workload on YCSB

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, nosql, ycsb, workload

I would like to compare the performance of cassandra and mangodb systems and besides the standard ycsb workloads I would like to write my own queries such as nested queries. is this possible and if so how to proceed. thank you

Comment: use https://github.com/nosqlbench/nosqlbench instead - YCSB is not very good test for Cassandra

Comment: thanks for response but i need it on YCSB. is it possible ?

Comment: up...help please